# Regular expression. Simple task

Tags: php, regex

How to match words **rugby and soccer**??
With help of regexp
Synonyms: American football, Association football, Canadian football, grid game, gridiron pastime, rugby, soccer, the pigskin sport

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Are you just looking for those words in a block of text?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex for this. Just use a simple array and iterate through it and check with `strpos`:

```
$string = 'My friends played soccer all winter';

$words = array('rugby', 'soccer', 'American football', 'Association football', 'Canadian football', 'grid game', 'gridiron pasttime', 'rugby', 'soccer', 'the pigskin sport');

$matchFound = false;
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strpos($string, $word) !== false) {
        $matchFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($matchFound);
```